# Highcharts - connect points with a line in scatter plot on hover

Tags: highcharts

I have a scatter plot in Highcharts and I would like to connect points with a line when hovering over a point.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you have several points in a scatterplot and connect two of the points only on hover?

Comment: yep. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scatter serie with lineWidth set as 2, then hide a SVG path (line) and catch mouseOver / mouseOut events to manipulate graphic.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/t96cds7o/3/

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function () {
                            this.series.graph.show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        this.graph.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

 // callback
 setTimeout(function(){
        chart.series[0].graph.hide();
 },1);
```